# Pass an intent from activity to a class extending Application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I was a given a module that I have to integrate on the application that I'm currently doing. But I am sort of lost when I encountered a class that extends an Application. What I'm trying to do is to pass intent to that class when a button is clicked. But I get an error in my manifest when I include the class. Probably because it is extending Application, not an Activity. My question is, is it possible to pass intent to a class extending Application? I'm new to java and android so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Here's my manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".RestIntent"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here's the RestIntent class:

```
public class RestIntent extends Application {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(){
         super.onCreate();
         SalesforceSDKManager.initNative(getApplicationContext(), new KeyImpl(), MainIntent.class);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

*My question is, is it possible to pass intent to a class extending Application?*

No, it is not.  See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Intents are received by Activities, BroadcastReceivers and Services, but not by Application objects.

Answer (score 0):

change your `Application` to `Activity`, if there are some methods to implement for the `Application`, create a delegate to your application in `Activity`.

```
public class RestIntent extends Activity {

     private Application application;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(){
         super.onCreate();
         application = getApplication;
         SalesforceSDKManager.initNative(getApplicationContext(), new KeyImpl(), MainIntent.class);
     }

}
```